# Rows to Columns with LEAD/LAG function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I would like to get help to achive a specific result with Oracle 11gR2.

First of all, I need to start with Table "RAW_DATA" arranged like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RAW_DATA
AS
SELECT 'MTL' AS EMH_CED,'ATW 25-55' AS EMH_ID,to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS EMH_DATE_HEURE,'AM' AS EMH_TYPE_MESURE,'A' AS EMH_PHASE,75 AS EMH_MESURE FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',100 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',98 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:29','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',75 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:29','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',100 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:29','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',98 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',84 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',100 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-03 17:17:57','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',98 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',91 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',89 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 15:06:07','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',0 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 15:06:07','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',0 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 15:06:07','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',0 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:22:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',23 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:22:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',24 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:22:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',24 FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:36','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',34 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:43','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',40 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:43','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',39 FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:28:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',51 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:28:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',58 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:28:12','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',57 FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:40:33','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',80 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:40:33','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',78 FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:41:02','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',73 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:47:10','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',83 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:55:39','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',98 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','A',0 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','B',0 FROM dual union ALL 
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:27:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',0 FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'MTL','ATW 25-55',to_date('2014-12-04 16:56:37','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'AM','C',96 FROM dual;
```

The final result I'm looking for is the following:

I need to have, on a single datarow, the "EMH_MESURE" for each value of "EMH_PHASE" ("A" , "B" and "C"). This result needs to be stored in three new columns respectivelly named "MESURE_A", "MESURE_B" and "MESURE_C".

After that, I need the datarow just before and after a zero crossing (this is when `MESURE_A=MESURE_B=MESURE_C=0`, with "RAW_DATA" sorted by "EMH_DATE_HEURE"). I also need the datarow corresponding to the zero crossings. In my context, there may be several zero crossings. Then, based on the table "RAW_DATA", the result I want to get is the following:

```
EMH_CED, EMH_ID,     EMH_DATE_HEURE,     EMH_TYPE_MESURE, MESURE_A, MESURE_B, MESURE_C
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 00:00:00       AM              84        91        89
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 15:06:07       AM               0         0         0
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 16:22:37       AM              23        24        24
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 16:27:43       AM              34        40        39
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 16:27:59       AM               0         0         0
MTL      ATW 25-55   2014-12-04 16:28:12       AM              51        58        57
```

So, I first transformed the column "EMH_PHASE" from "RAW_DATA" into 3 distincts columns ("MESURE_A", "MESURE_B" and "MESURE_C") with the code below.

```
WITH ROWS_TO_COLUMNS AS(
  SELECT EMH_CED
    ,EMH_ID
    ,EMH_DATE_HEURE
    ,EMH_TYPE_MESURE
   , MAX(decode(EMH_PHASE,'A', EMH_MESURE, null)) AS MESURE_A
   , MAX(decode(EMH_PHASE,'B', EMH_MESURE, null)) AS MESURE_B
   , MAX(decode(EMH_PHASE,'C', EMH_MESURE, null)) AS MESURE_C
FROM RAW_DATA
GROUP BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE, EMH_TYPE_MESURE
)
```

So far, it seems to do what I want, but I get some indesired nulls values.

Then, I filled nulls values with the values that came before each of them with this code:

```
NULLS_FILLED AS(
  SELECT EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE
   ,FIRST_VALUE(MESURE_A) IGNORE NULLS
       OVER (PARTITION BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC
         RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS MESURE_A
   ,FIRST_VALUE(MESURE_B) IGNORE NULLS
       OVER (PARTITION BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC
         RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS MESURE_B
   ,FIRST_VALUE(MESURE_C) IGNORE NULLS
       OVER (PARTITION BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC
         RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS MESURE_C
FROM ROWS_TO_COLUMNS
ORDER BY EMH_DATE_HEURE
)
```

The result after that operation was the one I was looking for at the beginning.

The next step is where I need help. I want to get only the LEADing and LAGing rows when `MESURE_A=MESURE_B=MESURE_C=0` (and I need to show this row too).

Right now, I can get the LAGing rows only, and the very last row of the Table, which I don't even want. I still have to figure out a way to get the 2 rows I'm missing while getting rid of the one I don't want.

I've tried different things without any good results so far. Help?

Here is the rest of my code, which need to be tweeked to get the desired result:

```
,RN_DATA AS(
   SELECT NULLS_FILLED.*, row_number() over (order by EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE) AS rn
FROM NULLS_FILLED
)

,DATA_GROUPED AS (
   SELECT RN_DATA.*, rownum - rn AS grp
FROM RN_DATA
WHERE MESURE_A>0 AND MESURE_B>0 AND MESURE_C>0
)

SELECT max(EMH_CED) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS EMH_CED
  ,max(EMH_ID) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS EMH_ID
  ,max(EMH_DATE_HEURE) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS EMH_DATE_HEURE
  ,max(MESURE_A) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS MESURE_A
  ,max(MESURE_B) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS MESURE_B
  ,max(MESURE_C) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS MESURE_C
  ,max(rn) keep (dense_rank first ORDER BY EMH_CED, EMH_ID, EMH_DATE_HEURE DESC) AS rn
FROM DATA_GROUPED
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY rn
;
```

Feel free to test my code with SQL Fiddle at:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6b2e0/4/0

Comment: This is a novel, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using ROW_NUMBER, FIRST, LAST functions. You simply need to use [LEAD, LAG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions086.htm#SQLRF00656) functions.

```
WITH rows_to_columns AS
(
         SELECT   emh_ced,
                  emh_id,
                  emh_date_heure,
                  emh_type_mesure,
                  Max (
                  CASE emh_phase
                           WHEN 'A' THEN emh_mesure
                  END) AS mesure_a,
                  Max (
                  CASE emh_phase
                           WHEN 'B' THEN emh_mesure
                  END) AS mesure_b,
                  Max (
                  CASE emh_phase
                           WHEN 'C' THEN emh_mesure
                  END) AS mesure_c
         FROM     raw_data
         GROUP BY emh_ced,
                  emh_id,
                  emh_date_heure,
                  emh_type_mesure), nulls_filled AS
(
         SELECT   emh_ced,
                  emh_id,
                  emh_date_heure,
                  emh_type_mesure,
                  First_value ( mesure_a) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND      unbounded following) AS mesure_a,
                  first_value ( mesure_b) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND      unbounded following) AS mesure_b,
                  first_value ( mesure_c) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure DESC RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND      unbounded following) AS mesure_c,
                  lead ( mesure_a, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                 lead_a,
                  lead ( mesure_b, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                 lead_b,
                  lead ( mesure_c, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                 lead_c,
                  lag ( mesure_a, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                  lag_a,
                  lag ( mesure_b, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                  lag_b,
                  lag ( mesure_c, 1) over (PARTITION BY emh_ced, emh_id ORDER BY emh_ced, emh_id, emh_date_heure)                                                                                  lag_c
         FROM     rows_to_columns)
SELECT   emh_ced,
         emh_id,
         emh_date_heure,
         emh_type_mesure,
         mesure_a,
         mesure_b,
         mesure_c
FROM     nulls_filled
WHERE    (
                  mesure_a = 0
         AND      mesure_b = 0
         AND      mesure_c = 0)
OR       (
                  lead_a = 0
         AND      lead_b = 0
         AND      lead_c = 0)
OR       (
                  lag_a = 0
         AND      lag_b = 0
         AND      lag_c = 0)
ORDER BY 3;
```

[Output:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6b2e0/6)

```
| EMH_CED |    EMH_ID |                  EMH_DATE_HEURE | EMH_TYPE_MESURE | MESURE_A | MESURE_B | MESURE_C |
|---------|-----------|---------------------------------|-----------------|----------|----------|----------|
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 |              AM |       84 |       91 |       89 |
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 15:06:07+0000 |              AM |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 16:22:37+0000 |              AM |       23 |       24 |       24 |
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 16:27:43+0000 |              AM |       34 |       40 |       39 |
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 16:27:59+0000 |              AM |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|     MTL | ATW 25-55 | December, 04 2014 16:28:12+0000 |              AM |       51 |       58 |       57 |
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
I'm not really an expert with SQL requests, so until now, I've always used the ROW_NUMBER, FIRST, LAST functions for this kind of treatment, so I have not really tried to use other functions... Moreover, I would not have thought of using new columns to store the result of the functions LEAD / LAG.
Your solution is surprisingly simple and do exactly what I want, thank you very much!